# UbuntuOne - can't sync files

Tags: ubuntu-one, setup

I have signed up for the Ubuntu one service today. I have been using Ubuntu lucid on my computer for a long time . I just find the Ubuntu one storage and sync service recently and I would like to set that for my backups.

I have been trying to fix the sync problems since morning. It is afternoon now. I tried to add computer on my account as needed. I had to install client tool first to make that work. Now I am not able to add any files to UbuntuOne sync.

When I try to add file/folder to sync on U1, it doesn't say anything. It doesn't start syncing file/folder too.

Here is the status of my `u1sdtool`. Whatever it is , I am checking whether it is syncing anything when I click on sync options from the folder right click menu choice.

```
sandip@living-room:~$ u1sdtool --status
State: QUEUE_MANAGER
    connection: With User With Network
    description: processing queues
    is_connected: True
    is_error: False
    is_online: True
    queues: IDLE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u1sdtool tells `description: processing queues`.
I think everything is working on your machine and you just need to wait the process is completed.
Please consider that:

1. the upload may take some time, especially if your add many/big files;
2. If you signed for the basic U1 account, you should not synch more than the available space (5 GB).

Comment: I think so . It worked mysteriously after sometime. Now my problem is totally different. I would put that in different question. Thanks by the way.